# PHP 5.4 php_ssh2 dependend library libssh2.dll can't register in window server 2008-x64

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, libssh2

Recently I deploy `php 5.4.17-nts`- version on windows `server 2008 -x64 R2 standard`. I download `php5.14.17` from http://windows.php.net/download/ and `php` extension `ssh2` (php_ssh2-0.12-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip) from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/.

But, after I add `ssh2` extension on `php.ini` file and check version of php, it throw an error message `"The program can't start because libssh2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".`

I execute command `regsvr32.exe` to registered `"libssh2.dll"`, but failed.

Interesting, if i use version `php` `5.3` and `0.11` version `ssh2`, it doesn't show any error message, `ssh2` version `0.11` for `php` `5.3` has only one dll `php_ssh2.dll` on `php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-nts-vc9-x86` folder. However on `php_ssh2-0.12-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip` contains 3 files one `php_ssl.dll` and another is `libssh2.dll` and `pdb` file.

Queries to know

1) `php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-nts-vc9-x86` contains only one dll (`php_ssl.dll`), but `php_ssh2-0.12-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip` contains 2 dll (`php_ssh2.dll`, `libssh2.dll`) and one `pdb` file, why it's different?

2) What is reason behind windows server 2008 - x64 R2 standard server doesn't registered `libssh2.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I almost wonder if this question might be better suited to serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Anyway you might have better luck with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).